# $\det(AB) \not = \det(A)\det(B)$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

What’s wrong with my reasoning?
$$\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right]\right)=2\times2-(-2)(-2)=0$$
$$\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right]= \left[\begin{matrix} 4&0\\0&4\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 4&0\\0&4\end{matrix}\right]\right)= 4\times 4 - 0 = 16$$
$$16=\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 4&0\\0&4\end{matrix}\right]\right)=\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \right)=\det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \right) \det\left(\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \right) =0 \times 0 = 0$$

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -2 \\
 -2 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -2 \\
 -2 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 8 & -8 \\
 -8 & 8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: This will be useful,. https://matrixcalc.org/en/

Answer (score 5):

$$\left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix} 2&-2\\-2&2\end{matrix}\right]= \left[\begin{matrix} 8&-8\\-8&8\end{matrix}\right]$$

You can check the resultant determinant is zero.

Comment: You are correct, I was wrong in my calculation.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}2&-2\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}8&-8\\-8&8\end{bmatrix}.$$